# Find values that exist in both excel files using an inner join method

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, merge

I need to find values that exist in both files.
For that reason I  had to merge vertically the 2 columns I wanted, removed duplicates and saved it as a new .xlsx file.

```
import pandas as pd

df_initial=pd.read_excel('receptors.xlsx')

df=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/GStamataki/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/nozeros-noligands-knockout/adipose-knockout.xlsx')

df["Proteins"] = df["Protein1"] + df["Protein2"] #merged the 2 columns

df_updated=df["Proteins"]
df_updated.drop_duplicates()

print(df_updated)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('cols.xlsx')
df_updated.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

This is how the column Proteins looks like after the merge of the two columns:
[image: Proteins col]

The output of this is :
[image]

Note that I tried to drop the index column that was created using `df_updated = df_updated.reset_index(ignore_index= False)` but it did not work.

Now, I want to compare the newly created .xlsx file with the receptors.xlsx one and print out only the values that existed in both. I am trying to do it using the inner join method, but it returns an empty dataframe.

```
df1= pd.read_excel('cols.xlsx')

df_diff = pd.merge(df1, df_initial, how="inner", on='Proteins', indicator="Exist")
df_diff = df_diff.query("Exist=='both'")
print(df_diff)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('merged.xlsx')
df_diff.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

receptors.xlsx :
[image: df_initial]

What am I doing wrong? I probably have made it super complicated but I couldn't think of another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close to reach your excpected result. However, you don't need to save `df_updated` to an Excel file to compare it with `df_initial`. You can directly use [**`pandas.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html). Also, there is no need for a `query` since the inner join will automatically keep the intersection of the two dataframes.

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

# --- Initialiazing Receptors
df_initial = pd.read_excel('receptors.xlsx')

# --- Cleaning-up Adipose Knockout
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/GStamataki/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/nozeros-noligands-knockout/adipose-knockout.xlsx')
df_updated = pd.concat([df['Protein1'],df['Protein2']], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates().to_frame(name='Proteins')

# --- Merging/Comparing Adipose & Receptors
df_diff = pd.merge(df_updated, df_initial, on="Proteins") # how="inner" by default
print(df_diff)

# --- Saving the result in a spreasheet
with pd.ExcelWriter('merged.xlsx') as writer:
    df_diff.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(<first file>)
df2 = pd.read_excel(<second file>)
df_join = df1.merge(df2, on='Protein')
```

Combine columns as you wish before merging.

Comment: Hello! I tried it and still getting an empty dataframe.

Comment: May be try removing spaces in those columns at the end before merging. Also try converting columns to lowercase to be sure